# Angular vs-repeat firing scroll events until hits bottom (and sometimes top)

Tags: angularjs

I have a few pages containing variable size collections of objects and one of them seems to duplicate the scroll-down event every time vs-repeat finishes and invokes the $digest all the way until it hits the bottom. The repeat statement is fairly nasty.

```
<div vs-repeat class="code-window" ng-init="dgnIdx = 0;">
    <div ng-repeat="dgn in codes = (displayDiagnosisCodes|codeLevel:'displayDiagnosis':hideAnswered|secondaryOrDo|codeSearch:diagnosisFilter) track by $index"
         ng-init="$parentIndex = $index;" style="overflow: hidden;" class="code-row"
         ng-class="{'active':$parent.dgnIdx==$index, 'child-row': dgn .role=='diagnosis', 'open': (dgn |codeChecked:DISPLAY_EXPAND)}">
        <div ng-repeat="choice in dgn ChoiceColumns track by $index"
            ng-click="setChoice(dgn , choice.value)"
             data-hotkey="{{$parent.dgnIdx==$parentIndex&&(''+($index+1))||''}}"
            ng-class="{'radio-col':true,'even': $even}">
            <input name="{{dgn .role+':'+dgn .id}}"/>
        </div>
        <div ng-bind="dgn.code"></div>
        <div ng-bind="dgn.title"></div>
    </div>
<div>
```

I've also got a few other pages that follow very similar patterns, but don't share this gnarly scrolling behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out it's a Chrome issue regarding a css feature that allows locking to an element while others are added to a set.

Adding "overflow-anchor: none;" to the parent element fixes it.

https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat/issues/156